# Member template function. Why doesn't this compile?

Tags: c++, templates

I whant to iterate in a member function over a list. In this code sample I am getting compiler error in for-line:

> Expected ; before it, it not declared, end not declared.

Why?
The function is even not used in code!

```
template <class T> bool Settings::saveSimpleList( QString k, const T & l ){
    //...
    for ( T::ConstIterator it = l.constBegin(), end =l.constEnd(); it != end; ++it )
    {
        QString itemValue = QVariant( *it ).toString();
        //...
    }

    return true;
}
```

I see, I am missing something in template programming.
Thank you for your hints!

Comment: BTW: I voted to reject your proposed edit of adding the `qt` tag. The essence of the question doesn't have any relation to QT.

Comment: Check out this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-to-put-the-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do this:

```
for (typename T::ConstIterator it = l.constBegin(), end =l.constEnd(); it != end; ++it )
{
    QString itemValue = QVariant( *it ).toString();
    //...
}
```

When writing `T::ConstIterator`, the compiler can either interpret that as "the static member `ConstIterator` of type `T`" or as "the type defined as `ConstIterator` by a typedef in type `T`".

If your intent is the second, as here, you need to add `typename` to tell the compiler.

Comment: +1: Thank you!!! I've read about typename in this context, but this is the first time I've using it.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler cannot know that T::ConstIterator is a type (because it does't know what T will be). You can indicate that by adding a `typename` in front of it.